# NSURLRequest setHTTPBody ending up in parameters of the server

Tags: iphone, ios, https, nsurlrequest

I am trying to send a POST request to my server, everything seems to be working fine, however all of the HTTPBody is ending up in the parameters of the request at the server end.

There is a Self-Signed certificate on the server which generates a AuthenticationChallenge that I am currently ignoring, thats working fine also.

However as I stated above the postBodyData is ending up in the wrong place on the server. The code I am using is showen below and is documented in Apples ios documentation library under NSURLRequest.

```
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postBodyData];
```

any help, suggestions or examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Have figured out the issue.
Because I was sending Binary data the content type was wrong, once i passed in an empty string it worked.

However I did not want to have no content type set so I have found a MIME type that works for this correctly as showed below.

```
[request setValue:@"application/octet-stream" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the Content-Length of your posted data in the request header also.  You should add:

```
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postBodyData length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

Comment: yep, I have added and tested that.. It is still ending up in the params of the server.. :( this is getting slightly painful now.

Comment: When you say "ending up in the params of the server", what do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: the body data ends up where the name value pairs normally are... dose that help explain it?

Comment: where do you expect to see your data instead?  Maybe you should show some of your server-side code where you are working with the request.

Comment: I will have to have a chat with the db developer tomorrow when hes in... the hope of this question was to try and find an error in my code if there was one.. if not then I guess we should start looking into the code on the server maybe? but from the conversation I had with him today, he had been doing his own requests that were working fine... its just mine that seem to be cause the issue. from what I understand is that the data should be ending up in body stream of the post request.. I think thats how to explaine it.. when he gets the post request the data is not in the body but in the param